# Разделение строк файла на части (bat)

Tags: cmd, bat

Нужно поменять в каждой строке файла четные и нечетные слова местами, результат в отдельный файл. Можно как-то сделать это с параметрами в tokens ?

Мой код:

```
@echo off 
chcp 1251 >nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Введіть перший параметр: 
set /p in_file=%~nx1
echo Введіть другий параметр: 
set /p out_file=%~nx2
if [%in_file%] == [] goto end
if [%out_file%] == [] goto end
set counter=1
set counter1=2

for /F "tokens=%counter%-%counter1%" %%a in (%in_file%) do (
 set "a=%%a"& set "b=%%b"
  echo !b!>>!a!>>%out_file%
  set /a counter=counter+1
  set /a counter1=counter1+1
)
type %out_file%
echo 
@pause
endlocal
:end
echo Ви не ввели один з параметрів!
echo
@pause
endlocal
```

Comment: можно и на bat. но ведь  powershell удобнее.. for $words in $list {   _$ ...}

Comment: Нужно именно на bat. Можете подсказать ?

Comment: Мне кажется, парсер **for** не примет количество слов (переменных) входной строки в виде переменной **%counter%-%counter1%**. Точнее он примет, но повторно уже обрабатывать не будет. Его нужно будет снова загонять в цикл. Поэтому лучшим решением, мне видится, вынос замены слов местами в отдельную процедуру. А уже потом нужно вызывать её (процедуру) из парсера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример обработки файла input.txt с помощью процедуры перестановки слов, предполагая, что в роли разделителя выступает пробел.

```
@for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (input.txt) do @if "%%j" neq "" @call :exchange %%i %%j



:exchange
@set "a="

:swap

@set "a=%a%%2 %1 "
@shift
@shift
@if "%2" neq "" (@goto swap) else (
@set "a=%a%%1
)

@echo.%a%

@goto end

:end
```